# Is the Multiselect SmartTarget Trigger an "OR?"

Tags: smarttarget, ambient-data-framework

I have a sanity check for SmartTarget (ST) trigger types.

For this [example (`sc_ua_browser`)](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-5EA5B2AA-F78B-4702-B906-8DBF4CDEB422) , if the ST user chooses multiple browsers, I believe the trigger is met and a matching promotion is presented if:

1. There's room for the matching region, for selected Publication and Page
2. All other triggers match (an "AND" between different triggers)
3. **But *any* of these values match (an "OR")** (correct?)

```xml
<trigger-type url-param="sc_ua_browser" name="Visitor - Browser" basetype="text">
       <list-of-values multiselect="true">
           <value>Camino</value>
           <value>Chimera</value>
           <value>Chrome</value>
           <value>Communicator</value>
           <value>Firebird</value>
           ...
           <value>Opera</value>
           <value>Phoenix</value>
           <value>Safari</value>
        </list-of-values>
</trigger-type>
```

For #3, the use cases might be:

- Present a ST promotion for certain U.S. States, but a different promotion for other States
- Present ST promotions for a selection of matching values (same promotion for multiple Campaigns, Emails, or anything with a querystring parameter that ends up in the ADF claim store, configured as a ST trigger)

**In other words, within the same *multiselect* ST trigger, the selected options create an OR relationship, right?**

*This doesn't make sense for triggers that have exclusive options (true vs. false), but those should have `<list-of-values multiselect="false">`.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is correct, there is an "AND" operator between triggers in a promotion, but an "OR" operator when selecting multiple values within a single trigger.

For the use cases you mentioned it is also possible to use filters instead of triggers. This allows to have a single promotion getting potentially all promotional content available, but then filtering the items by current claims values. For instance editors would tag promotional content in the CMS with the appropriate US State where a banner can be displayed, and based on the geo location of the visitor, the promotial content will be filtered to only show the appropriate banners available for the visitor's US State. This gets closer to a personalization scenario but can be interesting.

Comment: Nice, that would be filtering in the "What" (Content) part of a promotion, right?

Comment: Yes indeed the filters are defined there.